# In how many ways $10$ people can be seated at a round table as $2$ of them sit next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics

> In how many ways $10$ people can be seated at a round table as $2$ of them
>   sit next to each other?

We can look at the two of them that want to sit next to each other as a group. Then we have $9$ elements to seat at a round table. This can be done in $8!$ ways. Should we multiply this number by $2$ and is the answer $2\cdot 8!$?

Comment: Yes that is correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, and the multiplication by two is to account for the order within that group of two.